# mysql-server cant install on linux

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, reinstall

I removed the current mysql like that :

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
apt-get remove --purge mysql-client-core-5.5
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

And than when I want to reinstall I got some problems:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

//the output is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

and again

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

//the output is

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server-5.5 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5.47-0+deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.47-0+deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: mailx
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have already installed many times **mysql-common** and **mysql-clint-5.5**

What might be  problem?

Comment: In my case I had to run `sudo apt remove mysql-common` before the installation command started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this after 6 hours :)
Main problem was version number.After unistalling you should write like this:

To install mysql-server :

firstly install mysql-server-5.5

And to install mysql-server-5.5:

install mysql-common        `apt-get install mysql-common=5.5.47-0+deb7u1`

install mysql-client-5.5    `apt-get install mysql-client=5.5.47-0+deb7u1`

After install them :
  install mysql-server-5.5     `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

And finally :
 install mysql-server mysql-client `apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this script to resolve such problem in my ubuntu 20.04, see details in my comments:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Force install of missing deps
sudo apt-get -f install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"

#Remove the installed Apache 2
sudo apt-get purge apache2\*

#And followed by:
sudo apt-get purge mysql\*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get aut
sudo updatedb

#Reinstall full webstack if you want to.
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer you save my lots of time.